# XAMPP on Win7 too slow

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I'm running XAMPP 1.7.1 on Windows 7 Ultimate. Everything (Apache & MySQL) is working fine except for speed.

When I open http://localhost/, I must wait probably 1-3 seconds for view a webpage. In my opinion, it should be at most some hundreds miliseconds.

Basic facts:

- while waiting to load a localhost webpage, status bar says "Waiting for localhost..."
- CPU is still idle (no increased activity while loading)
- on localhost is no demanding PHP scripts, problems are when there is simple phpinfo() even if there is long heavy scripts.
- disabling MySQL server don't affect speed
- my PC: AMD Turion 64 X2; 1,6 GHz dual-core, 2 GB RAM, 100 GB HDD

I've made a little simple benchmark PHP script to test HDD/CSS speeds:

```
<?php

function getmicrotime() { 
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

function testReadWrite() {
 $timeStart = getmicrotime();
 $filename = "test.txt";

 file_put_contents( $filename, '' ); // prepare empty file

 for ( $i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++ ) {
  $a = file_get_contents( $filename );
  file_put_contents( $filename, $a . '.' );
 }

 return round( getmicrotime() - $timeStart, 3 );
} 


function testCpuSpeed() {
 $timeStart = getmicrotime();

 $var = '';
 for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++ ) {
  $var = sha1( md5( $i * $i * $i * $i * $i * $i * $i * $i * $i * $i ) );
 }

 return round( getmicrotime() - $timeStart, 3 );
}

echo "Read/write #1: " . testReadWrite() . "<BR>";
echo "Read/write #2: " . testReadWrite() . "<BR>";
echo "Read/write #3: " . testReadWrite() . "<BR>";
echo "CPU speed #1: " . testCpuSpeed() . "<BR>";
echo "CPU speed #2: " . testCpuSpeed() . "<BR>";
echo "CPU speed #3: " . testCpuSpeed() . "<BR>";

?>
```

My PC results:

- Read/write: 5.134 / 3.431 / 3.494
- CPU speed: 0.816 / 0.767 / 0.795

A webhosting results:

- Read/write: 7.768 / 7.69 / 7.371
- CPU speed: 0.232 / 0.234 / 0.234

One of my server's results (as idle computer nearly as my PC, but a little bit faster):

- Read/write: 0.088 / 0.168 / 0.185
- CPU speed: 0.191 / 0.189 / 0.189

So I don't think that it is because of my PC speed, but I'm sure that there's some another problem.
Do you have some experience with XAMPP speed on Windows 7 (or Vista) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is a bit overkill, but if you can't figure out *anything* else, try switching to WAMP, works flawlessly on Windows 7 for me.

Comment: Thanks! It resolved my problem :) Now I'm going to move all the vhosts from XAMPP to WAMP.

Comment: I have this problem too and also found the cause to be McAfee. I'm using the CodeIgniter framework and McAfee introduced delays when CI writes to log files. I turned McAfee off and the PHP app regained its former speed. I don't see an option to ignore specific programs per the BitDefender example...

Comment: Running XAMPP as an Administrator worked for me

Answer (score 44):

If XAMP is slow under windows 7, the firewall settings make no difference.
The Security Essentials anti-virus makes no difference.

To solve this problem, the two things that make a big difference are:

1)  in windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts   add the following lines:

127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1

127.0.0.1   localhost

2) If you're using PHP, in the XAMP php.ini file uncomment the  eaccelerator line:

zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_eaccelerator_ts.dll"

After these two changes, restart Apache and it will be way faster.

Comment: good things ! they helped me ! ( I didn't add the double IP line, as it makes no sense to me )

Comment: @bruno.karklis IF this entire Q and A is to be taken a face value, there are a number of 'causes' for XAAMP to run slowly.  There is NO one answer that is correct for everyone.

Comment: Also, run XAMPP as an administrator.

Comment: Hi, I'm following JoeV suggestions, but I'm getting 'Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_eaccelerator_ts.dll' because that dll file doesn't exist in my XAMPP version (PHP 5.5.24). What could I do?

Comment: didnt help for me, i have a vendor css, and a vendor js that are each taking 7 seconds to load.  not sure what give.  performance is otherwise good on the system.  thought it was xampp, might be laravel.

Comment: If you're also using as your web browser, Firefox (Version 84.0 (32-bit)), I verified that there is speed-up with JoeV's recommended technique; I counted the bouncing ball that signifies loading time; 1:3; 3:5; with technique : without; Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Not sure this might be the cause of your problems, but this might be an idea : do you have a line that looks like this :

```
::1 localhost
```

in your hosts *(it should be somewhere like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, if I remember correctly)* file ?

If yes, comment that line by adding a `#` at the beginning.

This way, the only line that's about localhost should be

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

which is an IPv4 address ; and the one you commented being an IPv6 -- which is quite not useful for what you are trying to do.

As I said, not sure your problem is related to this, but I've seen this sugestion help a couple of times for problems quite similar to your *(i.e. waiting a long time before doing anything on the server)*.

Comment: Yes, I have uncommented that line. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: Oh, too bad :-(  (I suppose you meant "commented", and not "uncommented)

Comment: I tried everything and I suppose that my hosts file was well written, fool of me, this fix the whole issue, thanks a lot!

Comment: uncommenting line with: 
127.0.0.1 localhost 
fixed the problem for me

Comment: Adding the line 127.0.0.1 localhost fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 15):

Comment the lines in PHP.ini with XDEBUG:

```
;[XDebug]

    ;zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
    ;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
    ;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
    ;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
    ;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
    ;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
    ;xdebug.remote_enable = 0
    ;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
    ;debug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
    ;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

```
    I disabled Bitdefeender -> no result
    I added lines to hosts -> no result
    I disabled xdebug - x2-x3 faster
```

Best regards 
Barto

Comment: this has made a big difference.  How odd it was that.

Comment: Does this disable debugging in general? Like, error logs, showing errors, stack tracing, etc?  Obviously in a development environment I want debugging enabled.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar issue with Win 7 + XAMPP. The problem was caused by the my antivirus software. When it was enabled even simplest PHP page was taking more than half a sec to open. Big PHP scripts with a lot of chained require_once()s tooked more than 1,5 seconds. With antivirus disabled everything was lightening fast (less than 100 miliseconds per simple pages, and about 500 miliseconds for really heavy stuff (100+ chained require_once())).

I am using bitdeffender and here is the solution for it:

1. Simple solution - just switch bitdefender to `game mode` when working with xampp
2. "Advanced" solution - go to `Antivirus -> Shield -> Advanced Settings -> Exclusions Tab` and there add exclusion for httpd.exe (located in your xampp installation/apache/bin/). Then go to `Antivirus -> Exclusions` and add exclusion for the directory where your php files reside.

Don't forget to restart apache after above steps.

Optionally you can install eaccelerator to speed the things even more.

As I side note: I found WAMP less mature as a project than XAMPP.

Side note 2: The best solution is to use your old PC as linux server and everything will work like a charm :-)

Answer (score 8):

After reading several answers - non of them helped (I even removed my antivirus).

What helped me dramatically is **disabling xdebug**. Now everything became very fast.

Comment: It helped me alot, thanks. But what if I want to keep xdebug on and also have highest speed?

Answer (score 2):

Two things can cause this issue.Anitivirus software and the settings in hostfile

1) in windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts add the following lines:

127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1

127.0.0.1 localhost

2) In your antivirus, exclude the document_root folder that contains your files (eg c:/www or c:/xampp/htdoc etc). To test this, you can also disable your anti virus temporarily but long term fix is to exclude the folder and subfolders

Answer (score 2):

My BUG  - XAMPP VERY SLOW

**My Xampp slow down and eventual stop was caused by warnings messages filling the php log - read on**

1 - Localhost/127.0.0.1 - no help

2 - Virus software interference - no help

3 - Port interference changing to 8080 - no help

4 - Wamp - same thing - no help

eventually things failed altogether with 500 errors.

C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log was almost a MB (957K)

too big for notepadd++ (my first clue I was on to something) and notepad took several minutes to render.

Thousands of messages of the "Strict' & 'Warning' type

**FIX**

changed the php.ini
display_errors=On to =Off  "There are several other error on/off switches in there, but this one did it for me."

nenamed log

restarted apache and mysql

Life is good.

Comment: An error log of less than a megabyte is *nothing* size-wise. that won't affect speed. Also, all you did with your "fix" is turning the display of errors off. Since you are most likely talking about a development server and not a production one, this is probably one of the least advisable things to ever advise someone to do - especially considering it probably has ZERO bearing on speed.

Comment: `(957K) too big for notepadd++ (my first clue I was on to something) and notepad took several minutes to render.` you're probably running a 486?

Answer (score 1):

How about giving Wamp Server a try?

The installation file is a lot smaller (16mb) compare to XAMPP (44mb).

[http://wampserver.com/](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why, but it helps and resolved my problem :) Now I'm going to move all the vhosts from XAMPP to WAMP.

Comment: Glad it worked.  WampServer definitely has a smaller footprint.

Comment: this is not the correct answer... the good answer is from JoeV . The questions is how to improve speed on xampp and not to kwon who is the fast.

Comment: I agree with Bruno, the right answer is from JoeV - that's a solution, this is just a fix.

Answer (score 1):

In `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` I had these lines commented

```
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
# ::1       localhost
```

and around 100 more lines of other rules.
The solution is to erase all those rules or to uncomment `127.0.0.1 localhost` and put in on top.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to the DB using 127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost" worked for me.

But i searched for another solution and came up with this:

In your **my.ini** file, uncomment the following line:

```
    # Change here for bind listening
    # bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
    # bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6
```

You'll end up having:

```
    # Change here for bind listening
      bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
    # bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6
```

Restart your mysql server and pages should load very fast without the 2-3 second delay.

Also, with this solution you don't need to modify your connection in your DB connect code, you can continue using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious -- check the size of your hosts file. My hosts file had ballooned to 450K due to Spybot adding exceptions for every malware site that ever existed even though those sites were mostly no longer active. Spybot commented these 10000+ entries with a copyright date of 2008, making them useless anyway.

I don't know if other spyware protection software does this, but the hosts file should be small enough so that XAMPP doesn't have to churn through the exception URLs every time it displays a page. BTW if you have any cracked software installed, which I don't condone of course, be careful not to delete the hosts exceptions that block online validation checking sites.

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue year back ago and finally find out what makes problem here.
what if your log (access,errors) files are going to such a huge that it will a take time to open even with notepad?

yes, you heard right xampp will create those files.

[image]

**Now If we have problem then there is solution too.**
we can rotate log files for every day. here is steps

1. Edit your httpd.conf in this path “Xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf”
2. You will find `CustomLog "logs/access.log" common`
3. replace with `CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access_%y-%m-%d.log 86400" common`
4. You can do same thing with **logs/error.log** files.
5. for more information of rotate program please follow https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html

i also agree with disble Xdebug will help too.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and it made XAMPP ways faster:

1. Assigned a new and unused loopback address to my site in the hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts). In other words I avoided using 127.0.0.1 used for other sites:

   `127.0.0.2    example.com`
2. In the Apache httpd.conf file added:

   `Listen 127.0.0.2: 80`
3. As I have several sites, I have subfolders under htdocs for each site. In this example the foldername is example.com, and that is where my site sits. So added a VirtualHost, again in my httpd.conf file, like so:

   `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
       ServerAdmin myemail@hotmail.com
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example.com"
       ServerName example.com
       ErrorLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/example.log"
       CustomLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/example-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>`
4. Restarted Apache.

After that, visiting example.com in the browser loads really quick.

Comment: This is what truly worked for my localhost.  Listen 127.0.0.2: 8080  really sped up everything.  I only am using it for 1 site.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem....

What I did is I uninstalled xampp which was on `C: drive` .

Installed it onto another drive `(E:)`...

and dont know but its working fine and fast....

Answer (score 0):

I use Avast antivirus and solved the problem with a simple click. Right-click the Avast icon and select Silent/gaming mode.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem, it was not related to anti-virus or firewall.  was easily fixed by ensuring local host was looking for 127.0.0.1.

i found good advice here:
[http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow

the instructions were as follows:
Edit file –
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment out the line by adding a ‘#’ in front:

## ::1 localhost

If “localhost” gets resolved to IP address “::1″, the request (when not able to find an IPv6 listening socket) will get routed back to IP address 127.0.0.1 (via timeout, fall-back, or some other mechanism), causing unnecessary delays for connections (e.g., typically anywhere from 1 second to 30 seconds).

Make sure that “localhost” is correctly mapped to the IPv4 loopback address “127.0.0.1” (…that this line is not commented out):
127.0.0.1 localhost