# XAMPP missing php_eaccelerator_ts.dll

Tags: php, apache, windows-8, xampp, server

In php.ini there's this line `zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_eaccelerator_ts.dll"` and following this guide at [XAMPP on Win7 too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891031/xampp-on-win7-too-slow) it says uncommenting that line makes XAMPP faster, but what's the point if the file wasn't even installed with latest Windows XAMPP installer.

So I snatched the file from Google and put in the dir, but now when starting servers Apache and the rest it gives this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajQmg.jpg (not enough rep to post pics yet).

Answer (score 1):

You should download and use one of the complied dll's below. It should match your PHP version.

> PHP 5.3.XX VC9: 
>   http://eac.qme.nl/eAccelerator_v1_0_GIT42067ac7e2_for_v5_3_XX-VC9.zip
>
> PHP 5.4.XX VC9: 
>   http://eac.qme.nl/eAccelerator_v1_0_GIT42067ac7e2_for_v5_4_XX-VC9.zip

Do not forget to rename downloaded file to: php_eaccelerator_ts.dll